# Find out which members verified a transaction in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I am using Hyperledger Fabric in combination with docker. My question is, how do i find out which peers verified a transaction in Hyperledger Fabric?

I use this code to instantiate my chaincode, which works:
`docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051" cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n mycc -l golang -v ${CC_VERSION} -c '{"Args":["entry","5"]}' -P "OutOf(2, 'Org1MSP.member', 'Org1MSP.member')"`

I am using peers from the same organization to verify the transaction.

All of my code works, but after running the code (which includes invokes), can i somehow check the block to see which peers endorsed the transactions that were made?

I have tried using the configtxlator to decode and view the block, but cannot find any information about endorsements in mychannel.block.

Answer (score 2):

Probably mychannel.block was old 
You have to check the latest block, where a transaction has been committed

------ OR -----

```
Use query with txid
```

A sample snippet of NodeJS

```
await this.channel.queryTransaction(trxnID, peer);
```

Took endorser block from large payload
                    "endorser": {
                      "Mspid": "nbdMSP",
                      "IdBytes": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n1O4Ak+jJMrQvOook+JRq3kHmCVKDig==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
                    },